# Distinguish between bubbled errors and field errors in Symfony 2 form theme?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

How can i distinguish between field errors and bubbled (form) errors? AFAIK the only `block` that controls this is:

```
{% block field_errors %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
    <ul>
        {% for error in errors %}
        ...
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock field_errors %}
```

I think i can't rely on `errors|length`: usually it's 1 for field errors, but can be 1 also for form errors :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like by default you are unable to separate these errors. But you can extend the basic [FormError](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormError.php) class and add some property, which will define the exact place where error appeared.

Comment: Ok. I love Symfony in all parts, but form one is really crappy. Hope that is going to be improved in 2.1. Look further for other answers, thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate why the "form one is really crappy"? We'd be happy to hear your feedback and improve the framework accordingly.