# symfony 2, collection of forms, validation error

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

My form type has a collection field:

```
$builder->add('affiliates', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new AffiliateFormType(),
    'allow_add' => true, 
    'allow_delete' => true, 
    'by_reference' => false,
));
```

In the template I have:

```
<table id="affiliates" >
    <tr>
        <th class="t1c0"></th>
        <th class="t1c1" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.affiliates.vars.prototype.affiliate_name)|e }}">Name</th>
        <th class="t1c2" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.affiliates.vars.prototype.affiliate_type_code)|e }}">Type</th>
        <th class="t1c3" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.affiliates.vars.prototype.address)|e }}">Address</th>
    </tr>
    {% for affiliate in form.affiliates %}
    <tr>
        <td class="t1c0"><input type="button" class="delete_button" value="Delete"/></td>
        <td class="t1c1">{{ form_widget(affiliate.affiliate_name) }}{{ form_errors(affiliate.affiliate_name) }}</td>
        <td class="t1c2">{{ form_widget(affiliate.affiliate_type_code) }}{{ form_errors(affiliate.affiliate_type_code) }}</td>
        <td class="t1c3">{{ form_widget(affiliate.address) }}{{ form_errors(affiliate.address) }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<input type="button" class="add_button" value="Add line" onclick="addAffiliate();"/>
```

Now javasript code (with jquery) for adding/deleting rows is:

```
<script language="javascript">

    var affiliatesCollection = $('table#affiliates');

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var rowCount = $('table#affiliates tr').length;
        affiliatesCollection.data('index', rowCount - 1);

        $('.delete_button').click(function(e) {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        });
    });

    function addAffiliate() {
        //get index
        var index = affiliatesCollection.data('index');
        affiliatesCollection.data('index', index + 1);

        //add row
        var cells = new Array();
        var cell = $('<input type="button" class="delete_button" value="Delete"/>').click(function (){
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        });
        var $cell = $('<td></td>').append(cell);
        cells[0] = $cell;

        for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        { 
            var prototype = $('th.t1c'.concat(i)).data('prototype');
            var cell = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);
            var $cell = $('<td></td>').append(cell);
            cells[i] = $cell;
        }
        var $newRow = $('<tr></tr>').append(cells);
        affiliatesCollection.append($newRow);
    }

</script>
```

Let say name is required field. The above code works fine except one case: When a row is added and deleted and added again, deleted index is not available anymore like first row's index=1, second row's index=3; and when the invalid form is submitted (for example name field is empty) form.isValid() correctly returns false, but validation errors are not shown beneath their respective elements. Can someone help me correct the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Bernhard Schussek's comment over here:

[How can I add a violation to a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717882/how-can-i-add-a-violation-to-a-collection#comment15613069_11745023)

You have to explicitly set `error_bubbling` to `false` ( defaults to `true` ) for collections to prevent the errors from bubbling up the tree into your main form and being shown there as global errors.

As you ( as far as i can see in your question ) don't have `{% form_errors(form) %}` inside your template those global form errors aren't shown but your collection's errors should present as global errors in your form right now.

Comment: I set error_bubbling = false as you recommended, but the problem persists. If error_bubbling=true, and {{ form_errors(form) }} is included in the template, then validation errors are shown in the global scope. Symfony just seems to be unable to associate those errors with actual collection entry fields, but somehow still manages to get the errors. I'm pretty sure it is related to indexes being skipped out. It occurs when new row is followed by another new row, and their indexes are not in sequence (because a row between them was deleted by user).