# Symfony Form CollectionType array validation

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an entity to send e-mails to multiple users with fields like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $message;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 */
protected $variables;
```

The message contains twig variables which I save in the `$variables` array. I'm using a `CollectionType` to render each variable and set it's data. That works.

The problem I currently have is that I cannot validate each variable if it's empty. I add them like this because I first need to save the message before checking if it has twig variables in it:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    /** @var Message $data */
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();
    if (!empty($data->getVariables())) {
        $form->add('variables', CollectionType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'entry_type' => TextType::class,
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank()
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

I found many different solution but they are all for a CollectionType that uses a different entity. In my case I simply save the array so if I have `{{ first_name }}` in my `$message` I would also have `a:1:{s:10:"first_name";s:0:"";}` in my `$variables`. I need to make sure that `first_name` is not empty after the initial creation.

Edit:

Using a Callback constraint in the entity I managed to prevent form submitting. The problem is now only visual. Currently the error message appears above the form. I'm looking for a way to show which fields exactly are empty and need to have a value.

Comment: Use a [Callback constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html)

Comment: @JackSkeletron Thanks, I already use a custom validator which works on every form but not here. I used the callback you suggested and now I cannot submit without filling in all the fields so that's good. But is there any way to have the form error message for a specific field? With this it's just an error message for the whole form.

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand but, you can add the violation/error message just to your field `$context->buildViolation('Something went wrong!')->atPath('variables')->addViolation();` and if you want you cand set `error_bubbling` to false [as specified here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717882/how-can-i-add-a-violation-to-a-collection)

Comment: Doesn't work. This adds the message under the collection type. So if I have multiple empty variables in the collection I don't get a message under each one but a single message under all of them. I think this is good enough for now. Will continue to research the issue